# Where is this used: {% someHTMLpage %}

Tags: html, django

As the title state, where is this used {% %} and for what is it used. I downloaded a Django template, and see this on all the html files.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/ Don't skip it if you are new to Django. That quickstart with solve a ton of basic questions about the framework.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for the advice. I'm throwing myself in the deep with this one, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tags provide arbitrary logic in the rendering process.
>
> This definition is deliberately vague. For example, a tag can output
>   content, serve as a control structure e.g. an “if” statement or a
>   “for” loop, grab content from a database, or even enable access to
>   other template tags.
>
> Tags are surrounded by {% and %} like this:

See this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#tags), can be helpful to clarify.

Comment: So, everything is a {% tag %} within the parenthesis?

Comment: Those aren't parenthesis. You should start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/